# vtiger 6 : i want subject - variable to email module

Tags: php, module, smarty, vtiger

From Email Module 'Subject' input field i want to put variable From Account module

Ex I want from Email Module form put a variable in subject field to take every time form is open. How can i do that?

in smarty layouts\vlayout\modules\Vtiger\ComposeEmailForm.tpl

```
<input data-validation-engine='validate[required]' class="row-fluid" type="text" name="subject" value="{$SUBJECT}" id="subject" spellcheck="true"/>
```

How can i take all variables from accounts and store it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending the email in a workflow, you can use any field to fill the Subject of a mail simply selecting it from the drop-down list (as in the figure)

[image]